# Certificate Error on installing PythonForS60

Tags: python, symbian, pys60

I am trying to create a small application for Symbian mobile phones using Python. Being a beginner i am having some trouble in setting up the environment for development. I installed Symbian3 SDK,PyS60 Application Manager ( for creating the .sis files to be installed on phones) and python 2.5.2 . I created a small hello world program and created its equivalent .sis file. But when i try to install it in Symbian 3 SDK, it gives me a 'Python Run time Error' ; i suppose it is because there isnt any python installed on the SDK. But when i tried to install the PythonForS60.sis file, it gives me a certificate error. I tried downloading the file through SDK, again it gives me a certificate error. I tried certifying the application through SymbianSigned.com, then it gives this error 
"The .sis file contains capabilities that are not permitted for Open Signed (Online)
FAILURE: Submitted .sis file uses a UID that is not allocated to the account holder matching this email address (0x20022ee8 )
FAILURE: Submitted .sis file uses a UID that is in protected range and is not allocated to the account holder matching this email address (0x20022ee8)" . Can somebody help me to solve this..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open `Application Manager` on your Symbian phone, go to settings and select `Software installation`. Change it from `Signed` to `All`. This will allow you to install applications which don't have a certificate, such as the `SIS` file you just packaged.

Also note that `PythonForS60 2.0` works only with `Python 2.5`.

Comment: Hi, tried that also.. its set to Signed to 'All' in my SKD . And i am using Python 2.5. Still having the same problem..:(

Comment: I hope you are not selecting any certificate when packing the `SIS` file?

Comment: I didnt do any..i downloaded the PythonForS60 version for Symbian 3 SDK and tried installing it in SDK ? what is the correct way for installing python inside SDK ?